# When using DataReader, is it better to execute SQL statements or stored procs from performance viewpoint?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, ado.net

I need to retrieve some fields from a table that match a given `ID`. Currently, I build a sql statement

```
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM d 
WHERE id = @id
```

Then execute it using the `DataReader`.

I could also write a stored proc that takes the `id` as parameter.

**I wanted to know which is more performance friendly.**

EDIT: I am using a parameterized query, edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: I don't think the `DataReader` is the thing you want to be considering - this class just reads the results of a query. I think your question would make more sense without the first 3 words.

Comment: A stored proc and **properly parametrized query** are going to perform just about the same. But it's important that you use **parameters** in your query - e.g. `SELECT ... FROM d WHERE ID = @ID` and you don't just *string together* your SQL statement. That practice would also open all doors for **SQL injection attacks** - twice a horribly bad idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are usually going to perform pretty much the same.

Note that differences can arise when this is called very frequently; the SQL code has to be parsed (but not necessarily re-compiled if the statement is recognized as being cached) every time when it is sent whereas the SP is precompiled, but that cancause suboptimal choices of indexes because the statistics aren't re-evaluated on each call.

Comment: SQL Server will compute the hash for an ad-hoc query and look that up in the query cache.  If the plan is found, it won't recompile or even parse the query.  Ad-hoc SQL queries have the exact same problems as stored procedures with suboptimal choice of indexes.

Comment: This is true if the query doesn't use parameters, but from the question asked I assumed parameters to be used. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: @Lucero Yes, parameters to be used.

Answer (score 4):

There is virtually no difference in terms of performance on modern versions of SQL Server.  Building SQL dynamically is generally considered a no-no- you want to use [parameterized SQL](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) to avoid SQL injection but that and stored procs will generally provide equivalent performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use prepared statements instead of a sql statement built by concatenating strings, then there is no difference with performance between a stored procedure and a prepared statement.  Both are compiled the first time they are run and cached in the sql server's query plans.

Answer (score -1):

It's going to be better to run the Stored Procedure, 1) because the execution plan is compiled ahead of time and cached, and 2) you dont expose your database to sql injection attacks. Without a code sample, it's impossible to say how you're currently doing it, but I would imagine you're just creating a single string and asking it to be executed which would be a **Bad Idea**.

Comment: A properly designed "ad-hoc" query with parameters is just as good as a stored proc - it is compiled once, kept in plan cache, reused - the same as a stored proc.

Comment: -1 Stored procedures and ad-hoc SQL are cached in the same way.  Using ad-hoc SQL does not result in more compilations (unless you set the "optimize for ad hoc workloads" server option)